# python ubuntu upstart job needs to restart itself

Tags: python, ubuntu, upstart

I have a Python script which I'm running as an ubuntu upstart job. I start it from the shell with:

```
sudo service my-service-name start
```

In the Python code for the service itself, I need to restart the service in some cases. Here's how I'm doing it:

```
import subprocess
import shlex
cmd = 'sudo service my-service-name restart'
subprocess.check_output(shlex.split(cmd), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

If I run cmd from the shell I can successfully restart my upstart job. If I run it from the job itself, the job stops but never starts again.

Is there some problem with upstart jobs starting themselves in this fashion? If so is there another way to get an upstart job to restart itself?

The reason I'm restarting the job is that I've updated the underlying Python code on disk, and I'd like to have the job restart so that it's running the new code.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the Python app code *from* the Python app? That is not a good idea...

Anyway, maybe by using the respawn stanza in the Upstart jobs, setting the signal handler for USR1 to the handler for TERM, then sending yourself the USR1 signal (or just sending yourself the TERM signal, but then you do not know when the auto respawn was for your special purposes or not).